# Python 3 unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' when calling max(list)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not a python programmer but I've been handed previously working code to run,
I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

It happens when calling min(item) on a List object

I don't know how to debug this, what does it even mean and why isn't it working? Is the list empty?

I tried changing min(item) to item.min() but it gave me error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'max'
```

Sorry I cannot show more code beyond this

Comment: My best guess would to look at the contents of the `List` and see if they're strings. Strings don't have a way to subtract, so min() wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, please provide the content of item.
@NinjaKitty min function works on strings

Comment: Oh my bad. I guess it does.

Comment: The other thing that doesn't make sense is why `item.min()` returned no attribute 'max', unless that's a typo